# Pass an array from android to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android

I went through all the posts shared in here, I still couldn't find my proper answer to run my code and make my app functional. I'll appreciate it if any of you who could help me on this issue.

I am calling bounded function getLocation() in tages  as mentioned: . The getLocation function is bounded to MyHandler in Android as mentioned in below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webView;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler ();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface (new Object(){
                       public void getLocation(){
                          mHandler.post (new Runnable(){
                            public void run(){
                               String[] values = {"3.16802","101.71309"};
                               webView.loadUrl("javascript:setLocation("+values+")");
                            }
                          });
                       }
                }, "MyHandler");
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/example/quick-start-example.html");

    }
}
```

The function setLocation in Android calls the method in JavaScrip as below, here we are passing the array into JS function:

```
function setLocation(val){
    var lat = val[0];
    var lng = val[1];
}
```

Please advice on this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can easily do a complex object like an Array.  You are starting to get into JSON territory.

In fact, I found some sample code that uses JSON to accomplish this.

Problem: You want to push array data from Java to JavaScript and/or from JavaScript to Java http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=4426&title=Exchanging%20Array%20Data%20between%20Java%20and%20JavaScript

Comment: Please advice how can I call a JavaScript function from android on load page, which means there is no click on button or over link from app. I want to call javascript function  from android whenever the application loads. please advice.

Comment: Correction: How to call a JavaScript function on load WebView.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are passing object like Array or List in Javascript function then first, you need to convert that object into JSON format like below:

```
 String[] values = {"3.16802","101.71309"};
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:setLocation('"+new JSONArray(values)+"')");
```

And in Java script function again you have to parse that JSON format input like below:

```
function setLocation(input){
var value=JSON.parse(input);
var lat = value[0];
var lng = value[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

^above comment, you can use onPageFinished to execute the loadurl part once your page is done loading like this:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setLocation("+values+")");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @JavascriptInterface
    public String[] displayName() {
        String ar[] = new String[2];
        ar[0]= "name1";
        ar[1] =  "name2";
        return ar;
    }
```

or to get Data in js function

```
   var t1 = Android.displayName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = gson.toJson(someArray);
```